# Only execute a command in Salt if a directory is empty

Tags: mysql, devops, salt-stack

I am trying to integrate the following command into a salt state:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/data/mysql/
```

but only when either /data/mysql is empty or mysql contains no databases.

Can anyone suggest a good way of doing this please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dare I state the obvious! Look at the folder and see, programatically of course

Comment: No please, do dare all you must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unless` inside your state file validating the existence of a path:

```
mysql_install_db:
  cmd.run: 
    - name: mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/data/mysql/
    - unless: file.path_exists_glob('/data/mysql/*')
```

**Edit**

As stated by @Christophe the previous version of the state had some issues . Updated the state based on that and on what I believe will be the best fit.

Comment: Would this work if the folder was empty? Basically I want to only run the command if that db hasn't been installed.

Comment: ahh I think this definitely works better over using an `onlyif`

Comment: This state would be invalid if the condition is not met. The condition is met if files are present in the directory (the exact opposite of what the OP wants). What about if the directory contains hidden files (starting with `.`).

Comment: You made a good point @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet. Indeed it will be invalid. There must be an else condition to make the state valid and also there must be a `not` in the statement. About the hidden files the return  will be false even though there are hidden files there, I believe in that point it is more about the use case.

Answer (score 4):

On any state, you can use `unless` or `onlyif` conditions. These conditions are commands launched on the minion while the states are evaluated.

For your need, you could use:

```
mysql_install_db:
  cmd.run:
    - name: mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/data/mysql/
    - onlyif: test -z "$(ls -A /data/mysql)"
```